# Tableau REST API Download Workbook

Tags: api, rest, tableau-api

Tableau has some [REST API calls](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____1)

Question 1: Does anyone know how to use the following call to download an online workbook? Sample code will be appreciated.

Question 2: Does any one know how to read and parse this twbx file?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? In order to do this, you'll need to sign in to Tableau Server, then retrieve the luids for both the site and the workbook you're trying to download. Have you managed to do any of these things? :)

Comment: Please edit out the content you have copied and pasted from tableau - makes it very awkward to read, Next, what programming language are you using?

Comment: (edit the page to remove material copied and pasted from the referenced link)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to send a GET request to a URL such as

```
https://YOURDOMAIN/api/2.0/sites/SITE-LUID/workbooks/WORKBOOK-LUID/content
```

You also need to send a header of your authorisation token like which is named `X-Tableau-Auth`

I suggest getting chrome and postman installed to test this kind of stuff out. Importing https://github.com/TableauExamples/Tableau_Postman as a collection will help